# Determinants of $3\times3$ matrices with full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

I have two $3\times3$ matrices $A$ and $B$ where
$$A = [c_1 : c_2 : c_3]$$  $$B = [c_1 : c_1 + c_2 : c_1+c_2+c_3]$$
where  $c_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $A$.
Given that $|A| = 1$, I am to find the rank and determinant of $B$.
Now since $A$ has a non-zero determinant, it will have a full rank, so $rank(A) = 3$ and all its columns will be linearly independent. It is obvious that $B$'s columns will also be linearly independent, so its rank will also be 3. Also, since the determinant is invariant under column operations and $B$ can be obtained by applying column operations to $A$, $|B| = |A| = 1$.

However, I was trying to follow an alternate line of reasoning to arrive at $|B|$...

Since the vectors $c_1, c_2$, and $c_3$ are linearly independent and have a size of 3, they are a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$. (I am not too sure about this part but I cannot think of how 3 linearly independent vectors of size 3 would not span $\mathbb{R^3}$).
Off course, $\mathbb{R^3}$ is also spanned by the basis $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$ which can be represented by the matrix

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which means we can obtain $A$ and $B$ by applying column operations to $I$ because they all have the same column space. Hence, $|A| = |B| = |I| = 1$.
However, my reasoning would also imply that every $3\times3$ matrix with a non-zero determinant (which will give it full rank) must have a determinant equaling 1.

Did I do something wrong?

Edit: Okay, so this will not be true for real numbers but will this be true for matrices with positive non-zero integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B= \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1& 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} A$.

Since $\det (CD) = \det C \det D$ you can see that $\det B = \det A$. This gives you the rank of $B$ in this case.

**Note**: In this example, you can reduce $B$ to $A$ by elementary row operations all of which have determinant 1. This is not true in general, if you multiply by a row scaling operation then the determinant changes.

Answer (score 1):

every 3×3 matrix A with a non-zero determinant will have 3 L.I vectors but det(A) may not be 1,because the vectors may not be unit vectors. For eg. the matrix

[[2,0,0][0,2,0][0,0,3]]